# How to optimize T-SQL query which depends on execution time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, query-optimization, non-clustered-index

I have a big (several millions rows) table with system events. I must to get recent event counts and I'm not shore how to do it in right way.

I created this view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[EventCounts] 
AS
  SELECT  
      (SELECT COUNT(1)
       FROM dbo.SystemEvents r
       WHERE r.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETDATE())
         AND r.Timestamp <= GETDATE()) AS last15minEventCount,
      (SELECT COUNT(1)
       FROM dbo.SystemEvents r
       WHERE r.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE())
         AND r.Timestamp <= DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETDATE())) AS from15to30EventCount,
      (SELECT COUNT(1)
       FROM dbo.SystemEvents r
       WHERE r.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE, -60, GETDATE())
         AND r.Timestamp <= DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE())) AS from30to60EventCount,
     (SELECT COUNT(1)
      FROM dbo.SystemEvents r
      WHERE r.Timestamp <= DATEADD(MINUTE, -60, GETDATE())) AS olderThan60minEventCount
```

This view returns:

1. < 15 minutes events count;
2. 15 - 30 minutes events count;
3. 30 - 60 minutes events count;
4. older than 60 minutes events count.

Now my code runs 4 times over all big table and I want to optimize it. I can't use preaggregations, because this counts depends on execution time. I can't use indexed view because of same reason.

I guess I can add nonclustered index on Timestamp column, but code still need to read whole table get this counts, right?

Could you suggest how to optimize my query?

P.S. last15minEventCount, from15to30EventCount, from30to60EventCount - very small part of all events.

Comment: You tried to use with "Execution plan"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion, you can change the approach and write your query like following.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[EventCounts] 
AS 
  WITH Boundary AS (
           SELECT Dateadd(MINUTE, -15, Getdate()) AS LOW, 
                  Getdate()                       AS HIGH, 
                  'last15minEventCount'           AS Label 
           UNION 
           SELECT Dateadd(MINUTE, -30, Getdate()) AS LOW, 
                  Dateadd(MINUTE, -15, Getdate()) AS HIGH, 
                  'from15to30EventCount'          as Label 
          --Additional Conditions 
          ) 
  SELECT Count(*), 
         B.Label 
  FROM   SystemEvents R 
         INNER JOIN Boundary B 
                 ON R.TimeStamp BETWEEN LOW AND HIGH 
  GROUP  BY B.Label
```

By this you will get the output into rows, you you need to transform as columns, which should be straight forward I feel.

This should be fast as the query is now SARGable, you need to put non clustered index on TimpeStamp column.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this :

```
 SELECT COUNT(1),
        SUM(case when r.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETDATE()) AND r.Timestamp <= GETDATE() 
                 then 1
                 else 0
            end) as last15minEventCount,
        sum(case when r.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE())AND r.Timestamp <= DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETDATE())
                 then 1
                 else 0 
                 end) as from15to30EventCount,
        sum(case when  r.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE, -60, GETDATE()) AND r.Timestamp <= DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE())
                 then 1
                 else 0 
                 end) as from30to60EventCount,
        sum(case when r.Timestamp <= DATEADD(MINUTE, -60, GETDATE()
                 then 1
                 else 0 
                 end) as olderThan60minEventCount,

 FROM dbo.SystemEvents r
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid one scan for each interval you can use `SUM(CASE ... END)`. But to make the make the query really fast you should maintain a table with the total count and create an index on the `TimeStamp` column:

```
CREATE TABLE SystemEvents
(
    [TimeStamp] datetime
)
GO

CREATE INDEX IX_SystemEvents_TimeStamp
ON dbo.SystemEvents(TimeStamp)

CREATE TABLE SystemEventsTotalCount
(
    TotalCount int NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO SystemEventsTotalCount VALUES ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SystemEvents))
GO

CREATE TRIGGER SystemEvents_TotalCount
ON SystemEvents
FOR INSERT, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @InsertedRows int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted);
    DECLARE @DeletedRows int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted);
    UPDATE SystemEventsTotalCount
    SET TotalCount = TotalCount + @InsertedRows - @DeletedRows
GO
GO
CREATE VIEW EventCounts
AS
WITH b AS
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN r.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETDATE()) AND r.Timestamp <= GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Last15MinEventCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN r.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE()) AND r.Timestamp <= DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS From15To30EventCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN r.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE, -60, GETDATE()) AND r.Timestamp <= DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS From30to60EventCount,
        (SELECT TotalCount FROM dbo.SystemEventsTotalCount) AS TotalEventCount
    FROM 
        dbo.SystemEvents r
    WHERE
        r.Timestamp > DATEADD(MINUTE, -60, GETDATE())
)
SELECT
    b.Last15MinEventCount, b.From15To30EventCount, b.From30to60EventCount,
    (b.TotalEventCount - b.Last15MinEventCount - b.From15To30EventCount - b.From30to60EventCount) AS OlderThan60EventCount

FROM b
GO

SELECT * FROM EventCounts
```